# How do I hide my NPC rolls from players?

Tags: tools, age-system, the-expanse-rpg, foundry-vtt

I'm planning on running a one-shot mission for my RPG group, and due to the geographic distance of the group (among other things), this will happen virtually.  I chose [Foundry VTT](https://foundryvtt.com/) as my platform since The Expanse RPG (through an [AGE system module](https://foundryvtt.com/packages/age-system)) is already supported.

The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to consistently hide NPC ability and attack checks from the players.  I can get part way there, using the [Actually Private Rolls](https://foundryvtt.com/packages/actually-private-rolls) and [Dice So Nice!](https://foundryvtt.com/packages/dice-so-nice) modules, but there's still *something* that gets shown to the players, at least some of the time.  Without either of these modules installed, the rolls show up in chat regardless of the roll chat setting, which seems to indicate the issue is primarily in the AGE system module.

During combat, I can hide everything from players by setting the  "Disabled during combat" option for Dice So Nice, but outside of combat the 3D dice still show up for players, even though I have the "Hide Private Rolls" option enabled for Actually Private Rolls and have set my rolls to private (Private GM Roll or Blind GM Roll) in the chat tab.  If I completely disable Dice So Nice, then all ability and attack rolls for NPCs are made public (although damage rolls are still at least obscured).

How do I make it so that all my automated rolls as GM are private unless I want my players to see the roll?  I could manually roll using the `/gmroll` command, but that seems counter productive.  Is it possible I'm just missing a setting on my NPC actors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [AGE system module wiki](https://github.com/vkdolea/age-system/wiki/Rolling-Dice), you simply have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when triggering the roll in order to make it private.

It also seems, counterintuitively, that disabling the Hide Private Rolls option for Actually Private Rolls makes it so almost everything acts exactly as you would like.  Damage rolls become obfuscated, but not hidden, regardless of the type of roll, but all ability and attack rolls as GM are completely hidden from the players.

---

**Update:**

The folks behind the AGE system module made a change to respect the chat box setting back in version 0.7.2 (dated 2021-06-07).  Now all rolls are based on the chat setting unless a modifier key is used to override it.

Answer (score 1):

### I have seen [this question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FoundryVTT/comments/kg0yv2/how_do_i_hide_dm_rolls/), they proposed this solution:

[Install the Actually Private Rolls package.](https://foundryvtt.com/packages/actually-private-rolls/)

And then do this.

> FYI, if you want to fix it temporary, you can edit the JS manually.
> Find the FoundryVTT directory (usually appdata/local/FoundryVTT)
> Then go in Data/modules/actually-private-rolls/
> Then edit accutally-private-rolls.js (you can right-click the file, edit with notepad) and add this line
> app.data["sound"] = null; between
> html.hide(); Line 15
> and
> } Line 16

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough, but this does not solve my problem at all.  I've already installed the Actually Private Rolls module, because the ability and attack rolls I made as GM were always public.

Comment: Yes, you need to apply the extra fix noted to get it to work fully.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Foundry user, so maybe I'm missing some context where Foundry automatically does things based on your rolls or something, but when I'm running an online game and want to roll something "behind the screen", I just use my physical dice.

If that's not an option (left my dice in my car or whatever), I use a private channel on our Discord, or even just Google's dice roller in a pinch.  (Discovered if you Google 5d8 it rolls it for you, seriously.)